# how to pipe output from a perl script to another via commandline or via a script

Tags: perl, pipe

I have on a windows machine (with perl interpreter on environmental path) the command :

```
 perl script1.pl | perl script2.pl
```

and the contents of script one are just:

```
  print "AAA";
```

and the contents of script 2 is just:

```
  $r = shift;
  print $r;
```

And the command doesn't pipe correctly. How do you do this? Also,
if you were to do it with a Filehandle, how would you run a perl script from another script concurrently. The following doesn't work:

```
    open F, '| perl script2.pl AAA';
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480069/how-can-i-read-piped-input-in-perl-on-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) in your main program removes elements from the special array `@ARGV` that holds the current invocation’s command-line arguments.

Write *script2* as a filter

```
#! perl

while (<>) {
  print "$0: ", $_;
}
```

or even

```
#! perl -p
s/^/$0: /;
```

To set up the pipeline from *script1*, use

```
#! perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, "|-", "perl", "script2.pl"
  or die "$0: could not start script2: $!";

print $fh $_, "\n" for qw/ foo bar baz quux /;

close $fh or die $! ? "$0: close: $!"
                    : "$0: script2 exited $?";
```

Multi-argument `open` bypasses the shell’s argument parsing—an *excellent* idea on Windows. The code above assumes both scripts are in the current directory. Output:

```
script2.pl: foo
script2.pl: bar
script2.pl: baz
script2.pl: quux
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be reading from **STDIN**, **shift** manipulates command-line arguments.

The following snippet explains it.

```
cat script1.pl
print "AAA";

cat script2.pl
print <STDIN>;
```