# Run directly python script in windows console

Tags: python

Is there any way to run directly  python script in windows console such as Unix system?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3.3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shebang Notation: Python Scripts on Windows and Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574453/shebang-notation-python-scripts-on-windows-and-linux)

Comment: i think emulating unix behavior on windows isn't really a good idea. try something like what Stefan Näwe suggested below, or maybe fiddle with the "start" or "open" commands. if you really want your system to behave like a unix, you should consider using a unix or linux based one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or create a .BAT file that doubles as a python script:

```
@echo off
rem = '''
echo This is "%~f0" before Python

python -x "%~f0" %*

echo This is "%~f0" after Python

goto :end
'''

print "------------- Python code starts here --------------"
import sys
print sys.path
print sys.argv
print "------------- Python code ends here ----------------"

rem = '''
:end
rem '''
```

Answer (score 0):

Just double clicking a file with `.py` extension on Windows executes the script.

Comment: is there any way to run from CMD?

Comment: you mean besides `python script_file.py`? I'm not on windows and can't test, but try simply entering the filename and hitting Enter.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Python GUI + command line, you can run any `.py` file.

http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.3.2/#download