# Getting the argument

Tags: python

When I run this following lines as: python MyApp.py arg1 arg2
I get the expected result:

```
['MyApp.py', 'arg1', 'arg2']
```

BUT - when I run it as: MyApp.py arg1 arg2
I do not get the arguments:

```
['MyApp.py']
```

How cat I get the arguments without explicitly using python?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    print (sys.argv)
```

Comment: " without explicitly using python" Huh? You are writing a Python script. What does that mean?

Comment: Can you share more of your source file? I can't reproduce the issue you're talking about with the code you've provided.

Comment: This is all my code. I want to get the arguments without explicitly using python?

Comment: Again. What do you mean by " without explicitly using python". You can't write a Python script  without explicitly using Python.

Comment: Try it with this shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: @DeepSpace He means in the terminal he does not want to have to type it like this `python MyApp.py arg1 arg2` he wants it to be ran like so `MyApp.py arg1 arg2`.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the clarification...

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and it works for me (on Windows 10 with Python 3.6) - maybe you have set up the default application for .py files in a weird way that overrides the arguments?

Comment: What happens when you add the line: `    print ("Arguments should appear after this:") before the line `    print (sys.argv)` and run `MyApp.py arg1 arg2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute Python scripts in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934675/how-to-execute-python-scripts-in-windows)

Answer (score -1):

**If you are using a Linux Distribution**, open the Terminal and type

```
which python
```

You will get a path where your default Python executable is stored. Enter this path as a first line of your code with shebang, i.e., `#!`. For example, my path is: `/usr/bin/python`, then I can do the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
print sys.argv
```

now, in your terminal, go to the directory where the file is stored. Suppose the name of the file is `check.py`. Make it executable using the following command:

```
chmod +x check.py
```

Now you can run your program by typing: `./check.py arg1 arg2` and it will execute as it should.

**For Windows**, you need to make sure that Windows is associating the right Python executable to execute your `.py` files. Even if it's associated correctly, sometimes Windows stripes off arguments from the command.

I am not a very heavy Windows user. You can check this blog: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/12/14/problem-passing-arguments-to-python-scripts-on-windows/

Comment: I use Windows  os

Comment: @DuduArbel that's a very important thing to bring up when answer a Python question.

Comment: I looked it up and Windows does not look at the shebang.

Comment: I don't know how to do this on windows. Maybe this question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7574453/3160529