# windows shebang to specify 32 version of python3.6 does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, 32bit-64bit, shebang, pywinauto

**in brief:**

`#!/usr/bin/python3.6-32` doesn't work

**in details:**

I'm trying to connect to an 32 bytes app using pywinauto.

I have installed python 3.6 x64 and then python 3.6 x32.

I installed the python launcher (it was zipped my python folder containing all versions)

in cmd `py` send:

`Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit`

and `py -3.6-32`send:

`Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC
 v.1900 32 bit (Intel)].`

I ran this script.py to check if the shebangs given by the docs works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6-32
import sys
sys.stdout.write("hello from Python %s\n" % (sys.version,))
input()
```

I then drag and droped the script.py into cmd windows, it sends:

`hello from Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:
06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]`

Comment: I think the shebang that you have used is for a linux path "/usr/bin/python3.6-32". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574453/shebang-notation-python-scripts-on-windows-and-linux

Comment: thanks for your help: they are mentioned in the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines

Comment: Yeah, you can customize the virtual commands in windows too.https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/

Comment: output of `ftype | findstr -i python`