# Can't pass zero arguments to Python program running on Windows command line

Tags: python, windows, command-line, command-prompt, command-line-arguments

When I run the following file directly through the command line

```
# winargs.py
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

by placing that file in a directory in `PATH` and running the command `winargs.py` in either Window Command Prompt or Powershell, I get an unexpected trailing empty string.

```
['winargs.py', '']
```

I would expect it to output only the script name like so:

```
['winargs.py']
```

## Windows Configuration

I previously could not pass arguments at all before but I followed [the instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640971/windows-is-not-passing-command-line-arguments-to-python-programs-executed-from-t) to add a `"%*"` to the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command` registry key and I can now pass arguments so running `winargs.py a b 1 2` outputs `['winargs.py', 'a', 'b', '1', '2']`. I am using the Anaconda distribution of Python for Windows and had that Python set as my Default Program for running `*.py` files. The registry key I modified after setting the default is

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command]
"C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\python.exe"  "%1" "%*"
```

## Larger Problem with `argparse`

This is causing larger difficulties when running scripts written with `argparse` that only have required positional arguments. Instead of printing a help message, it interprets that empty string as the first positional argument. For example, for the program

```
# winargparse.py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("first_arg")
parser.parse_args()
```

I see no output running the command `winargparse.py` from both the Command Prompt and PowerShell, but expect it to print the default `argparse` help message as it does when I run `python winargparse.py` which looks like

```
usage: winargparse.py [-h] first_arg
winargparse.py: error: the following arguments are required: first_arg
```

How can I get Windows Command Prompt to run my Python files both without arguments and with arguments?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574453/shebang-notation-python-scripts-on-windows-and-linux

Comment: It is a side effect of adding `%*` in registry. It makes Windows to call python with at least one argument for your python program even it is an empty string in case of no arguments.

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov Is there some other wildcard so that it passes no empty string when there is nothing following the script name?

Comment: @JamesCagalawan As long as I know, anything you pass in command line will be treated as argument. Can you show full registry record - may be you use unneeded quotas in it around `%*`?

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov It is `"C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\python.exe"  "%1" "%*"`, I've also updated the question with this information.

Comment: @JamesCagalawan Try to remove quotas around `%*` as they are not present in answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640971

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderUshakov, I really appreciate it. That did the trick, please submit as an answer if you have time so I can accept it.

Comment: You are welcome. Ii is great that you’ve solved  your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have unneeded double quotes around `%*` in your registry record. They make Windows pass an empty parameter if there are no arguments. Just remove these quotes.