# Is my NODE code not working because im using windows not linux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, package.json

I get this error in windows CMD:

```
> fastify-website@1.0.0 build:get-releases C:\Users\Karol\Desktop\wbs
> src/scripts/downloadReleases.js fastify/fastify build-temp/releases/ v0.11.0

'src' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My package.json:

```
"name": "fastify-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A static website builder for metalsmith",
  "scripts": {
    "build:cleanup": "rimraf build-temp",
    "build:create-temp-folder": "mkdirp build-temp",
    "build:get-releases": "src/scripts/downloadReleases.js fastify/fastify build-temp/releases/ v0.11.0",
```

Description

so basically npm start works till it gets to script "build:get-releases"...
I tried messing with package json but didnt help, also, the directory src/scripts/downloadReleases.js DOES exist.

Is it because it was written typically for linux and im using windows?
Because im ready to install linux if its true, but i need confirmation

(PS i downloaded this straight from github and it should be working, so my assumption was linux can read this specific content of package.json file properly)

Comment: Assuming `src/scripts/downloadReleases.js` is a node script, what is the output if you add `node` it to like so: `node src/scripts/downloadReleases.js ...`

Comment: try replacing the "/" in paths by "\" for windows

Comment: thanks @Kaddath, that solved the issue, however im getting next error. i guess ill just install linux. thanks again i wouldnt find it on my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is because you are not using linux.

[Windows has no support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574453/shebang-notation-python-scripts-on-windows-and-linux) for [shebangs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), which [downloadReleases.js](https://github.com/fastify/website/blob/master/src/scripts/downloadReleases.js) uses. You can see it on line 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

That line tells the operating system where to find the proper interpreter for the script. A simple fix that you or the author could make would be to use the interpreter in the command like so:

```
node src/scripts/downloadReleases.js fastify/fastify build-temp/releases/ v0.11.0
```

This change would allow either windows and linux users to run the scripts as long as they have `node` installed.