# PyCharm opening when I run .py file from batch file

Tags: python, sockets, batch-file, server, pycharm

I have created a **batch file** that is opening a **Python Code** that I programmed
in **PyCharm**. But when I open the **batch file** that is opening my **Python Code**,
then **PyCharm** randomly opens and I don't know why.

For example:

If I have created a
**Python Code** that says `print('Hello World')` then when I have made a **batch file**
that should open that **code** then the **batch file** should just say `Hello World`.
But in my case, instead nothing happens and **PyCharm** is opening instead. And I don't know why.
I even tried to do copy the same **code** into **Visual Studio Code**, a another programming program.
I did the same **code**, created a **batch file** that should open the **Python File/Script** and even then
**PyCharm** opens even if the **code** I created comes from a another program.

So the **code** looks like this:

```py
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 3759

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), PORT))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established!")
    clientsocket.send(bytes('Welcome to the server!', "utf-8"))
```

and the **batch file** goes like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
color 0a
"c:\Users\golle\PycharmProjects\Test\server.py
```

And I know just to notify that there isn't any errors. So the **code** I created is opening a server and the
**batch file** is opening that server by going into its folder and starting the **server.py**
file which contains the **code** for the server. And when I click on the **batch file**, then **PyCharm** opens and the server isn't opening.

Because what should happen is that when I click on the **batch file** then a server should come up
without **PyCharm** opening. And when I login to the server thru a **client.py** then the server window
that I opened thru the **batch file** should say:

```
Connection from {address} has been established!
```

But it isn't working.

The weird thing is that it worked just like I wanted it to a couple of days ago, but yesterday when I was gonna try it again, it didn't work and just like I said, **PyCharm** is randomly opening.

btw: I created the server with help from a video from this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lbfe3-v7yE0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason Pycharm is randomly opening is because on your Windows computer, that's the default application to open for Python files. Running `"c:\Users\golle\PycharmProjects\Test\server.py"` is essentially the same as double clicking on it from the file explorer.

What you need to do is have python execute the file, instead of trying to run the file directly.

It would look something like this:

```
python "c:\Users\golle\PycharmProjects\Test\server.py"
```

This assumes that python is in your PATH.

Comment: For those that want to be able to run their Python file on Windows by double clicking on it, without having to type `python my-script.py`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574453/shebang-notation-python-scripts-on-windows-and-linux