# Activating a Virtual Environment when running .bat file using Windows Scheduler

Tags: python, batch-file, pycharm

Using pycharm, I finished my first python program.
I am attempting to run a bat file with Windows Scheduler.
The python script has lots of dependencies. They are available in the virtual environment I am using.

1. I tried activating my virtual environment using the activate.bat file in the directory of the venv.
   The code of the scheduled bat file looked like this:

   ```
    C:\Users\PavelWorkXPS\Anaconda3\envs\TestEnv\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\activate.bat "D:\Dropbox\Toolkit\Python\Unusual_Options_Activity-ToS\main.py"     pause
   ```

When running this, Pycharm would launch because it is my default .py extension handler.

2. I modified the bat file to use the interpreter python.exe from within the virtual environment folder, hoping it would have access to the dependencies.

   ```
    C:\Users\PavelWorkXPS\Anaconda3\envs\TestEnv\python.exe "D:\Dropbox\Toolkit\Python\Unusual_Options_Activity-ToS\main.py"  pause
   ```

Output would tell me it still can't see the dependencies.
[image]

I used this earlier stackoverflow post for help, but it only explained the reason
[why pycharm was opening by itself.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60466364/pycharm-opening-when-i-run-py-file-from-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

Conda was the reason for the problem. When I switched to doing it with a plain virtual environment, it stored all the downloaded repos in a folder inside of the folder with the script. Then I setup the bat file and all worked fine.