# Cannot open python file by double clicking in windows when importing

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pygame

I have simple python file main.py:

```
import pygame
print("Hi There")
input()
```

I have installed pygame, and the default app to open .py files is set to python.exe, but when i double click the file it won't open. If i try the same without the import line it can run with no problem.

I tried to create run.bat file to open the python file:

```
python main.py
```

This is the console output:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Hi There
```

Everything runs without problem when using run.bat file.

So my question is why i cannot open the main.py file by just double-clicking, and how to make it work?

Comment: that's because file association points to a different python version than the one you have in your path. That's the "magic" of windows. create a simple python script containing `import sys` then `print(sys.executable)` then `input()` and  run by clicking or with python prefix you'll see I'm right

Comment: You can add a shebang notation on the top. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574453/shebang-notation-python-scripts-on-windows-and-linux

Comment: @HussainBohra - Does a shebang do anything on a Windows platform?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks

Comment: @lit it does, in python 3 only. But I don't recommend it

Answer (score 0):

From comment by @Jean-FrançoisFabre. The problem was that when I was just double-clicking the python file was running from different version of python than when I run it from cmd. By using of simple python script containing `import sys` and then `print(sys.executable)` I was able to change the default python version for opening .py files in windows.

Comment: be careful when associating to .py files, as you could lose the arguments (%*). I recommend not to do that by hand, but to install python properly