# Python version trouble

Tags: python, environment

I am aware that this question keeps popping up, but I have tried most of the methods mentioned in the replies that I have seen for other questions and I am still facing this problem. I need my scripts to run with python 3.8.5 that I have installed at the location "C:\Python\Python3.8.5".

When I run `py --version` in the terminal, the output I get is `Python 3.8.5`. This is exactly as expected.

But when I make a script called print_sys.py as such,

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

and then run this by typing `.\print_sys.py`,
I get the output as `2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]`

On the other hand, if I run this same script by typing `py print_sys.py`, I get the output as `3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)]`

I want it to run the script with python3.8.5 when I try to execute the script by typing `.\print_sys.py`

In case it helps this is what my path variable in system variables look like.

[image: System Variables > Path]

This is what my PYTHONPATH variable in system variables looks like.

[image: System Variables > PYTHONPATH]

And this is what my path variable in user variables looks like

[image: User Variables > Path]

I suspect that it's that last python 2.7 from the windows build tools that is the problem but I don't see how that could be since python 3.8.5 comes first.

EDIT: I finally found a solution that works for me. I referred to [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHxUlXmfrt0) to find out how to change the file association for .py files on my machine. I still don't understand why just changing the order of the path variables didn't work so if anyone has any idea about that your answers will still be appreciated.

Comment: Your system has both `python2` and `python3`. You need to uninstall `python2` or run your scripts using `python3` command such as - `python3 print_sys.py`.

Comment: But I think that ```python2``` is required for windows-build-tools so I don't think I can just uninstall it. I might be wrong about this but since it was installed automatically I think I might break something if I delete it.

Comment: Nothing gonna break, Its time to uninstall it, for backup, you have python3

Comment: You could try changing your environment variable to have python3 supersede python2 by reordering the position. In this case, it looks like lower paths are prioritized. Try moving "C:\Python\Python3.8.5" below "C:\Users\adamj\.windows-build-tools\python27. Note that this may cause system problems if python2 is a dependency.

Comment: did that and still the same problem persists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shebang Notation: Python Scripts on Windows and Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574453/shebang-notation-python-scripts-on-windows-and-linux)

Comment: not really as this requires me to use the py launcher and as I've said before that already works. What I need is a way to change my file association for .py files

Comment: Define a `PY_PYTHON` environment variable to tell `py` what the default python should be — i.e. `PY_PYTHON=3`.

Comment: did this, it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your script as executable you need to tell the system what interpreter it should use - otherwise default interpreter will be used and that might not yield result you expect. Add shebang on top of your script and rerun, both should return the same output.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# your code
```

I'm not windows user though, shebang might or might not work depending on what environment you use to execute scripts. If you use MinGW or Ubuntu subsystem then you `should` get the same behavior as on linux.

Also in windows you can associate extension with program which executes it. I'd check what program you have associated with `*.py` extension. There must be a registry entry for that too.

Comment: OP is on Windows. That shebang line does nothing on Windows.

Comment: nope, I already tried that. With the shebang lines as either ```#!usr/bin/env python3``` or ```#!"C:\Python\Python3.8.5\python.exe"``` I'm still getting the output implying that the program is being interpreted by ```python2```

Comment: So you are executing script in cmd? If so then maybe check the default program for *.py extension?

Comment: okay so i tried the assoc and ftype commands that i found somewhere to find the file association and as suspected that points to ```python2```. Now how do i change that? From what I've found so far, putting ```python3``` higher than ```python2``` should automatically change the filetype association, but i might have misunderstood what i read.

Comment: This would be the correct answer, but OP is on Windows, not Linux.

Comment: Just try, by changing file sasociation there is nothing you can break (I mean I'm 99% sure). You can also go through the `backend` - I don't know if you have `regedit` on your version of windows, but long ago when I was working on windows I used to find related entries there (beware it's a bit of an epic maze).