# How do I enter the msys2 /usr/bin directory in Python on Windows?

Tags: python, msys2

I am trying to write a file in the/usr/bin path so that my program can be ran from anywhere.

This is the code

```py
os.chdir("/usr/bin")
writetofile("slang", "cd " + pdir + " && python3 slang.py $1 $2 $3")
```

And pdir is set with `os.getcwd()`

However, it gives me an error.
`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '/usr/bin'`

I tried removing the "/" but that didn't work either.

And I can't include the full path to /usr/bin because the MSYS2 path might not be the same for everybody.

How do I get Python to change the CWD to /usr/bin?

After running `python -m site` I get this output:

```
sys.path = [
    'C:/msys64/home/*me*',
    'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python310.zip',
    'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10',
    'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
    'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: 'C:/Users/*me*/.local' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: 'C:/Users/*me*/.local/lib/python3.10-mingw_x86_64/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Comment: This looks like you're using a native Windows `python.exe`, not one compiled with msys. You can't see synthetic directories under names that msys synthesizes unless your Python interpreter itself was compiled with msys.

Comment: If you don't have permissions, things often look like they don't exist.  My guess is your std user doesn't have write permissions in /usr/bin.  As... you shouldn't (it would be a big security hole).

Comment: @JLPeyret, what makes you think the OP is trying to _write_ to `/usr/bin`, vs just `chdir()` there? (They can very much get this problem just trying to use `chdir()` if they're on Windows, because Windows _doesn't have_ a `/usr/bin`).

Comment: probably that their user can't write there unless they are in an elevated permission mode (i.e. maybe an admin on the cli).

Comment: Maybe you can read the OP? *I am trying to write a file in the/usr/bin*

Comment: _Ahh_. Thank you for calling that out -- I was indeed focusing on the title -- but that would be a different error message: an EPERM / "permission denied", not 
"cannot find the path specified"

Comment: Well, I really don't know.  This whole thing looks fishy, and  yes, I as wondering about /usr/bin on Windows too.  The OP can go and digest these comments and see if they need to adjust anything.

Comment: @JLPeyret, the other thing is that the directory mapped to `/usr/bin` is typically owned by whoever installed the copy of msys on Windows, unless they installed it as Administrator, so having write there is not so unusual as it would be on a UNIX system.

Comment: @JLPeyret (...if you're not familiar with msys, it's a lightweight competitor to cygwin -- a compiler toolchain and standard C library that acts like a UNIX libc even on win32, and presents a UNIXy-looking filesystem and set of APIs to applications that were built against it; perhaps in that context the question makes more sense? It's what "Git Bash" is built on, and thus rather widely used)

Comment: @JLPeyret I am using the python3 that I installed with pacman, so I don't think there should be a permission error. Plus, I can write into /usr/bin with a Shell Script file, so why not a Python script?

Comment: @OK9090 I am going to defer to Charles on that - I think they truly have a better handle than me here.  But perhaps you can 1) post a **minimal** example of your Python code failing? with the error message?  2) the path of the exe for the Python that is being used (`python -m site` may help here) - it may very well be a windows Python vs msys Python thing and 3) perhaps you can try writing a file /usr/bin under Windows?  Right now, we have an error on a python script, but no Python code to be seen, nor a way to judge if it's git bash Python or Windows Python.  Welcome aboard.

Comment: @JLPeyret I added stuff that will hopefully help, if you need more just tell me.

Comment: disclaimer:  not a Python-on-git-bash guy.  But normally, on Linux/macos you'd set that information on the script itself, via a shebang, rather than a shell that cd's and runs.  This is a question here about [shebangs and Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574453/shebang-notation-python-scripts-on-windows-and-linux).  googling "shebang git bash python" may give you some idea.  a typical shebang:  `#!/usr/bin/env python`  Again, your approach *may* be the better one, but I can't really help with it - I've run Win Python on Win, never Unix Python on Win.  good luck.

Comment: You shouldn't touch `/usr/bin`, it should be controlled by your package manager. Either put the program into `/usr/local/bin` (does it exists in MSYS2?), or into some other directory, which you then add to the PATH.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat /usr/local/bin does not exist in MSYS2.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found is creating a separate shell script file (with the code to write into /usr/bin), and then running that script in a subprocess.