# Is it possible to open a text document through a python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, file

I want to open a text document using the *(right click, then)* 'Open with' *(, then 'Choose another app')* menu on Windows and select a Python Script.

The script should then be given the file's contents and location as two variables with which it can do anything.

Is this possible?

Comment: I believe "open with" will pass the path to the given file as a parameter that you can use to open that file. The easiest way to do that will be to use a batch file that calls python passing in your script and the path given to the batch file. You and potentially skip the batch file and use the python script directly if you use [Shebang Notation: Python Scripts on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574453/shebang-notation-python-scripts-on-windows-and-linux)

Comment: _The script should then be given the file's contents and location as two variables_ I believe the script would only receive the file **name**, not its **contents**.  (But if the script knows the file name, then it can certainly _get_ the contents.)