# Python window doesn't stay open when double-clicking the .py file

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I think I'm just to dumb because I've had very little experience with Python.
But I can't seem to figure out why the terminal window closes a split second after opening.

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

while True:
    text = input("What do I need to say? (Type 'exit' to end)\n")
    if text.lower() == 'exit':
        break
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

That's the whole thing.
In the terminal in VS Code it works, of course, but not the when you just click the file.
And I don't want to have to do it through a cmd terminal and looking up the file.
Because I have other .py files that I can open by just double-clicking; but those don't show me how I did it there.

Comment: Don't double click it, type in terminal `python main.py` and you should see why it's closing (presumably and exception)

Comment: The fact that it exits without interaction indicates that it doesn't find a required library, or something else is wrong when you run it. How did you install `pyttsx3`? Ultimately the easiest solution might be to create a double-clickable `.cmd` file (if you are on Windows, with my sincerest condolences) or shell script which sets up the environment correctly (perhaps a virtual environment?) and then launches the Python script.

Comment: i just opened my cmd and ityped "pip install pyttsx3" and that succesfully installed.
after that I just typed this code above and thats all

Comment: But I know its possible to double click it so i dont want to have to do it by opening a cmd prompt and typing the address to my file and the run it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shebang Notation: Python Scripts on Windows and Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574453/shebang-notation-python-scripts-on-windows-and-linux)

Comment: no sorry its a bit confusing to me